# Regular expression to get value in between parentheses

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression to get the value in between parentheses. I expect a value without parentheses. For example, given:

```
value = "John sinu.s(14)"
```

I expected to get `14`.

I tried the following:

```
value[/\(.*?\)/]
```

but it gives the result `(14)`. Please help me.

Comment: Use `value[/\((.*?)\)/, 1]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may do that using

```
value[/\((.*?)\)/, 1]
```

or

```
value[/\(([^()]*)\)/, 1]
```

Use a [**capturing group**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and a second argument to extract just the group value.

Note that `\((.*?)\)` will also match a substring that contains `(` char in it, and the second option will only match a substring between parentheses that does not contain `(` nor `)` since `[^()]` is a [**negated character class**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) that matches any char but `(` and `)`.

See the [Ruby demo online](http://rextester.com/RAQ29139).

From the [Ruby docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D):

> `str[regexp, capture] → new_str or nil`
>   If a `Regexp` is supplied, the matching portion of the string is returned. If a capture follows the regular expression, which may be a **capture group index or name, follows the regular expression that component of the `MatchData` is returned instead**.

In case you need to extract multiple occurrences, use `String#scan`:

```
value = "John sinu.s(14) and Jack(156)"
puts value.scan(/\(([^()]*)\)/)
# => [ 14, 156 ]
```

See [another Ruby demo](http://rextester.com/RNWR37636).

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to use non-capturing look arounds like this

```
value[/(?<=\().*(?=\))/]
```

`(?<=\()` - positive look behind make sure there is `(` but don't capture it
`(?=\))`  -  positive look ahead make sure the regex ends with `)` but don't capture it

Comment: Alternatively you can leave out the look ahead and change the capturing mechanism instead: `/(?<=[(])[^)]*/`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
/(?<=\\()[^\\)]+/g
```

which selects string inside brackets without brackets

> Only thing you need is "positive lookahead" feature

Follow [this link](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html) for more info about `positive lookahead` in special groups.
I don't know if it is supported in ruby

Comment: That's a positive lookbehind, which is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this regular expression

```
/\((.*?)\)/
```

- `\(` will match your opening parenthesis in the string
- `(.*?)` creates a [capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html)
- `\)` will match your closing parenthesis

Answer (score 0):

Do you wish to extract the string between the parentheses or do that using a regular expression? You specify the latter in the question but it's conceivable your question is really the former and you are assuming that a regular expression must be used.

If you just want the value, without any restriction on the method used to obtain it, you could do that quite simply using [String#index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-index) and [String#rindex](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-rindex).

```
s = "John sinu.s(14)"

s[s.index('(')+1 .. s.rindex(')')-1]
  #=> "14"
```