# Regex - String within the first parenthesis of string

Tags: regex, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I am trying to get an overview of the visitors of my website by using AWS Logs Insights.

My query looks like this:

```
fields @timestamp, @message
  | parse @message /(?<@ip>(?<=User-Agent)(.*)(?=X-Forwarded-Proto))/
  | stats count() as requestCount by @ip
  | filter ispresent(@ip)
  | sort requestCount desc
```

Some of the results are like this:

```
=Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 15_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.1 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1,
=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.1 Safari/605.1.15,
```

I am trying to get the string within the first parenthesis:

- iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 15_1 like Mac OS X
- Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7

I tried `| parse @ip /(?<@device>(/\((.*?)\)/)/` [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49647692/regular-expression-to-get-value-in-between-parentheses) but it doesn't work.

Any ideas how I could make it work?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the result for the given pattern, you might use another named capture group (instead of a lookarounds, you might also match the text):

```
User-Agent=[^()]*\((?<@device>[^()]*)\).*X-Forwarded-Proto
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XLLDwn/1).

With both capture groups:

```
User-Agent(?<@ip>[^()]*\((?<@device>[^()]*)\).*X-Forwarded-Proto)
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gpjQMI/1).